# Django Foreign Key Empty : How to do?

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have a MySql database, with a system based on Django, of a Club with members.  The Member Class has a field "member category" attached to the 'mcatid' database field.  It's setup with a foreign Key to Class Membercategory.  See below

The Problem: when in the Memberdatabase I leave the mcatid field empty, then when I run code associated with their table, things break.  Django notices there is no membercateogry of "nothing", or NULL. Logically, it's ok.  I don't (yet) have the category, or some other reason. How do i define the class(es) so that Django does not complain if there is no related foreign key defined?

==========Classes===========

```
Class Member(models.Model):
    membercategory = models.ForeignKey(Membercategory,related_name=
    "%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related", db_column='mcatid', 
    help_text='Category of membership.',
    verbose_name='Member Category',null=True,blank=True)

class Membercategory(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=45, db_column="category")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,db_column='timestamp')
    objects = models.Manager()
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'member_category'
    ordering=['title']
    class Admin:
        pass
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.title)
```

Comment: your null=True, blank=True should already take care of it. Did you add that constraint after running `migrate` ? If so, you might have to run makemigration again

Comment: Thanks. To be honest, I haven't yet gotten into migrations.  For a long time, making changes to the models.py and the same change in the MySQL database always worked.

Comment: To be honest, I haven't yet done migrations. Making changes to the models.py and in the database worked.  I read about migrations, then did a "manage.py make migrations" and "manage.py migrate" and then tried again.  Error moved now into the related analysis of the data using Pandas.  The record in the Member table where the mcatid field is blank caused Pandas to fail on "KeyError: 'id' when it could not find the foreign key.  

I'm now going to assume the migrate had a positive impact on Django and will now look into how Pandas is not doing as I thought I told it. 

Thanks!!